# Django, adicionar dados a partir de um form

Tags: django

estou querendo inseir dados no banco de dados a partir de um form, este form está funcionando, mas ele contém muitos campos do tipo foreing key, então se eu não adicionar préviamente os dados eles não aparecem como opção no formulário. Então minha dúvida é como eu posso adicionar dados nestes campos diretamente do formúlário? Queria algo igual quando estamos adicionando dados no django-admin, se o campo está vazio é possível adicionar diretamente daquele modelo. Não sei se minha explicação ficou clara.

aqui o models.py

```
class Add500(models.Model):
    Kuni = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='国')
    MODELO_CH = (
        ('D25 SMOOTH', 'D25 SMOOTH'),
        ('D26 500W', 'D26 500W'),
    )
    Modelo = models.CharField(choices=MODELO_CH, max_length=20, verbose_name='機種')
    Kiban = models.CharField(max_length=6, primary_key=True, verbose_name='機番')
    TsukiBun = models.CharField(choices=TSUKI_BUN_CH, max_length=2)
    SoBanBeO = models.ForeignKey(SousaBanBetsuOki, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='操作盤別置')
    C2JK = models.ForeignKey(Cable2JiKikan, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='２次機関ケーブル')
    Jb41 = models.ForeignKey(JB41, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='JB41')
    ChipCon = models.ForeignKey(ChipConveyor, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='チップコン', null=True)
    Jb52 = models.ForeignKey(JB52, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='JB52')
    Jb61 = models.ForeignKey(JB61, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='JB61')
    Painel = models.ForeignKey(Panel, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='パネル')
    opBox = models.ManyToManyField(OpBox, verbose_name='OP Box')
    B2PC = models.ForeignKey(Box2PC, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='2PC')
    Trans = models.ForeignKey(Transformer, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='トランス')
    ToChu = models.ForeignKey(TokuChu, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='特注')
    BiKo = models.TextField(verbose_name='備考')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Kiban
```

aqui o pedaço do forms.py

```
class Toroku500(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Add500
        fields = '__all__'
```

aqui o views.py

```
def KibanToroku500(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form500 = Toroku500(request.POST)
        if form500.is_valid():
            form = form500.save()
            return redirect('/seiko/torokusentaku/')
    else:
        form500_class = Toroku500()
    return render(request, 'seiko/add500_form.html', {'form500': form500_class})
```

Ele está funcionando, porque eu adicionei vários valores préviamente no banco, mas em produção o usuário vai adicionar os valores de acordo com a demanda, por isso gostaria de uma forma de adicionar diretamente deste form.

se alguem puder ajudar agradeço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que percebi você consegue fazer isso pelas views.

```js
def KibanToroku500(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form500 = Toroku500(request.POST)
        if form500.is_valid():
            form = form500.save(commit=False)
            form.SoBanBeO = #o que liga ao outro model que nao da para ver 
            #### e faz igual para os campos que quiser 
            form.save()
            return redirect('/seiko/torokusentaku/')
    else:
        form500_class = Toroku500()
    return render(request, 'seiko/add500_form.html', {'form500': form500_class})
```